# webpack: understanding source maps when working with CSS

Tags: css, webpack, source-maps, webpack-style-loader, mini-css-extract-plugin

**Introduction**

I have already setup bundling for my Javascript files with `webpack` in my project. Now I am in the process of adding CSS files to the `webpack` configuration. So far, I have been including the CSS files manually in the HTML header by adding `<link>` elements for every CSS file I depend on (e.g. bootstrap, my own css, etc.). Obviously this is not very elegant and using `webpack` would be much better, so I would like to replace the link elements and bundle them via `webpack`.

This should be easy, everything is pretty much documented in the webpack documentation. After reading the documentation and experimenting a bit with `webpack` I have arrived at the configuration below which already works.

**Problem**

The problem with my current setup is that I would like to have *proper* source map support and that does not seem to work. By proper, I mean that I expect that when I run a development build with `webpack` and I inspect some element in Chrome DevTools, that I will see from which file and which line in the file a certain CSS class originated and that I can click on the CSS rules and the browser jumps to that file.

I do not want to have inline styles in the head element, because then the browser will show something like `.foobar {      <style>..</style>`, rather then `.foobar {        app.css:154`.

With my current setup I have all CSS files combined (but not minified) into one `app.css` file. This means that if I inspect a bootstrap class such as `.btn` then it appears as `.btn {       app.css:3003`. However, what I want to achieve is that the browser shows it as `.btn {     bootstrap.css:3003`.

So now I am trying to understand how `webpack` and the different plugins such as `css-loader` and `min-css-extract-plugin` apply CSS source maps, and how I can configure them to achieve a proper debugging experience.

I am not sure how relevant this is, but when I navigate in DevTools under Sources to `webpack://./bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css` I see that it only contains a single line:
`// extracted by mini-css-extract-plugin`.

**Webpack Setup**

**index.js:**

```
window.jQuery = require('jquery/dist/jquery');
require('bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
require('bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap');
/* other dependencies */
```

**webpack.config.js:**

```
const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module: {
    rules: [ 
        { /* Javascript rules excluded */ },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,

            use: [
                {
                    loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
                },
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader',

                    options: {
                        sourceMap: true
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,

            use: [
                'file-loader'
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
            use: [
                'file-loader'
            ]
        }
plugins: [
    new UglifyJSPlugin (),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                              template: 'app/index.tpl.html'
                          }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: devMode ? 
                               '[name].css' :
                               '[name].[hash].css' 
                             })
],
```

**Conclusion**

It seems I just passed the [rubber duck test](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2018/04/23/strange-and-maddening-rules/). While I was writing this I arrived at a solution. I will still publish the question, maybe it can help others.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was also using the `mini-css-extract-plugin` for development and not just for production. I thought that I needed to do that, because when at first I was using the `style-loaded` I would get styles included in the header and the browser would show me all styles as `.foobar {      <style>..</style>`.

However, the actual problem seemed to be, that I was not using `devtools`. So the solution was to add `devtool: devMode ? 'cheap-module-eval-source-map' : 'source-map',` to the `webpack` configuration to conditionally use the `style-loader` plugin during development builds and `mini-css-extract-plugin` during production builds.

**webpack.config.js**

```
        {
            test: /\.css$/,

            use: [
                {
-                   loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
+                   loader: devMode ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                },
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader',

                    options: {
                        sourceMap: true
                    }
                }
            ]
        },

  /* ... */

+ devtool: devMode ? 'cheap-module-eval-source-map' : 'source-map',
```

Comment: No longer works with webpack 5.